# Forward to (*.jsp) page within a java Class after a SQL Statement

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I don't have deep experience regarding Java and facing the following (small) issue:

How to execute a forward to page within a java Class after a SQL Statement?
Using Jersey 1.19

Code in Resource:

```
@POST
@Path("/remove")
public String removeUserId(@FormParam("uid") int uid) throws Exception {

    FormData test = new FormData();
    return test.removeUser(uid);

}
```

Code in Sub-Resource:

```
public String removeUser(@FormParam("uid") int uid) throws Exception {

    con = DbConn.apiUserProfileConn().getConnection();
    Statement stRemoveUser = con.createStatement();
    String queryRemoveUser = "DELETE FROM users " + "WHERE id = " + uid;

    int rsRemoveUser = stRemoveUser.executeUpdate(queryRemoveUser);

    return "user: " + uid + " has been removed";

}
```

when I try:

```
@POST
@Path("/remove")
public Response removeUserId(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, @FormParam("uid") int uid) throws Exception {

    URI uri =    uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path("removeUser/index.jsp").build();
    return Response.seeOther(uri).build();

}
```

then the I get to `removeUser/index.jsp` but the user has not been removed from DB table. This is because the uid is not being passed to removeUser in the Sub-Resource. So how can I passe the uid to remove and in the same time execute a kind of call (forward and/or redirect) to: `removeUser/index.jsp`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks! but it didn't help.. the uid is being passed to the url: removeUser/index.jsp?uid=xx as QueryString, but the user has not been removed form DB table.
I have to pass the uid to the method removeUser() in the Sub-Resource which execute the  SQL: DELETE form xx WHERE id = xx. and after that it should redirect/forward to the jsp page.

Comment: The JSP page should just display a kind of information/text to the user etc.
e.g. "The user: First Name Last Name with ID: xx has been removed."

Removing the user should happen in the method: removeUser() in Sub-Resource class.
Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that when you changed the `removeUserId()` method, you removed the call to your subresource. If both removal and redirect works independently, try to call `removeUser()` before you do the redirect.

```
@POST
@Path("/remove")
public Response removeUserId(@FormParam("uid") int uid) throws Exception {
    // remove the user
    FormData test = new FormData();
    test.removeUser(uid); // you may want to use the return to indicate a success/failure

    // redirect
    URI uri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path("removeUser/index.jsp").build();
    return Response.seeOther(uri).build();
}
```

Later in your index.jsp, you may use `request.getParameter("uid")` to get the id of the user.

Comment: Yes, This is it... really simple.
The mistake was that I tryied to return the: test.removeUser(uid) and this won't work as the Type of the method is: Response and am returning String.. that's why I got the error: String can't be converted to Response.